# Is a SELECT then UPDATE as efficient as an UPDATE only in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have code like this inside my stored procedure. There's no code between the SELECT and the UPDATE other than some checks on the data returned and a THROW that happens if the data is not correct.:

```
SELECT col1 FROM b WHERE c = @c
UPDATE b SET col2 = 99 WHERE c = @c
```

Can I expect this to do the same number of data accesses as the following:

```
UPDATE b SET col2 = 99 WHERE c = @c
```

Note that the reason I am doing this is I would like to check the rowcount after the first select and THROW an error before starting the UPDATE. If there is no performance difference it just makes my code look a lot cleaner for this case only.

Comment: I need the select because I select into a local variable and then call a stored procedure later on.

Comment: 1. There is difference 2. Keep in mind that the first code is prone to race condition

Comment: Both are two different operations. `Select`  and `Update` is not same as `Update`. `Select` will do a table hit and next `update` will also do a table hit

Comment: So there's no concept of caching the row data from the first table hit like in Oracle in SQL Server?

Comment: @zerkms - Can you explain what you mean by "prone to a race condition" ?  Thanks

Comment: Of course, there is performance difference, you are executing two statements versus one. However if the row you are updating is not in buffer cache there is little difference, becacuse  reading fron the disk is much more costly than read from the buffer cache.

Comment: Have you considered checking rowcount after UPDATE?: UPDATE b SET col2 = 99 WHERE c = @c; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN ... END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference, it will do 2 operations, but if you need to have the col1 value could do it like this:

```
UPDATE b SET @col1 = co1, col2 = 99 WHERE c = @c
```

or if you need more complicated things like the previous value, then you can use output

```
update b set col2 = 99 output deleted.col2 WHERE c = @c
```